# How do you kill roscore/master?

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ask because ps aux | grep roscore returns nothing. But if I try to run roscore it says it is already running.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52778/how-do-you-kill-roscore/master?/) by [absolutelyNoWarranty](https://answers.ros.org/users/4004/absolutelynowarranty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Select the console that is running roscore and press Cntrl+c

---

Originally posted by [dptsrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3957/dptsrk/) with karma: 140 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use

```
$ ps aux | grep ros
```

there is a rosmaster process.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7